# python conda environment install package order

Tags: python, anaconda, conda, miniconda

Creating an environment conda (anaconda/miniconda python) from a package list file (see bottom of message).

I've specified matplotlib version to 3.0.2, after creating env, I run python then:

```
Python 3.7.9 (default, Aug 31 2020, 12:42:55)
[GCC 7.3.0] :: Anaconda, Inc. on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import matplotlib
>>> matplotlib.__version__
'3.3.2'
```

I've to `conda uninstall matplotlib` then `conda install matplotlib=3.0.2` to have then good version of matplotlib.

I think basemap package enter in conflict with matplotlib that's why this happens.

How can I do a clean environment creation without having to uninstall/install matplotlib ?

```
# This file may be used to create an environment using:
# $ conda create --name <env> --file <this file>
# platform: linux-64
_libgcc_mutex=0.1=main
basemap=1.2.0=py37h856778e_4
blas=1.0=mkl
bzip2=1.0.8=h7b6447c_0
ca-certificates=2020.10.14=0
certifi=2020.6.20=pyhd3eb1b0_3
cftime=1.2.1=py37heb32a55_0
curl=7.71.1=hbc83047_1
cycler=0.10.0=py37_0
dbus=1.13.18=hb2f20db_0
expat=2.2.10=he6710b0_2
fontconfig=2.13.0=h9420a91_0
freetype=2.10.4=h5ab3b9f_0
geos=3.8.0=he6710b0_0
glib=2.66.1=h92f7085_0
gst-plugins-base=1.14.0=hbbd80ab_1
gstreamer=1.14.0=hb31296c_0
hdf4=4.2.13=h3ca952b_2
hdf5=1.10.4=hb1b8bf9_0
icu=58.2=he6710b0_3
intel-openmp=2020.2=254
jpeg=9b=h024ee3a_2
kiwisolver=1.3.0=py37h2531618_0
krb5=1.18.2=h173b8e3_0
lcms2=2.11=h396b838_0
ld_impl_linux-64=2.33.1=h53a641e_7
libcurl=7.71.1=h20c2e04_1
libedit=3.1.20191231=h14c3975_1
libffi=3.3=he6710b0_2
libgcc-ng=9.1.0=hdf63c60_0
libgfortran-ng=7.3.0=hdf63c60_0
libnetcdf=4.7.3=hb80b6cc_0
libpng=1.6.37=hbc83047_0
libssh2=1.9.0=h1ba5d50_1
libstdcxx-ng=9.1.0=hdf63c60_0
libtiff=4.1.0=h2733197_1
libuuid=1.0.3=h1bed415_2
libxcb=1.14=h7b6447c_0
libxml2=2.9.10=hb55368b_3
lz4-c=1.9.2=heb0550a_3
matplotlib-base=3.3.2=py37h817c723_0
mkl=2020.2=256
mkl-service=2.3.0=py37he904b0f_0
mkl_fft=1.2.0=py37h23d657b_0
mkl_random=1.1.1=py37h0573a6f_0
ncurses=6.2=he6710b0_1
netcdf4=1.5.3=py37hbf33ddf_0
numpy=1.19.2=py37h54aff64_0
numpy-base=1.19.2=py37hfa32c7d_0
olefile=0.46=py37_0
openssl=1.1.1h=h7b6447c_0
pcre=8.44=he6710b0_0
pillow=8.0.1=py37he98fc37_0
pip=20.2.4=py37h06a4308_0
proj4=5.2.0=he6710b0_1
pyparsing=2.4.7=py_0
pyproj=1.9.6=py37h14380d9_0
pyqt=5.9.2=py37h05f1152_2
pyshp=2.1.2=py_0
python=3.7.9=h7579374_0
python-dateutil=2.8.1=py_0
pytz=2020.1=py_0
qt=5.9.7=h5867ecd_1
readline=8.0=h7b6447c_0
setuptools=50.3.0=py37h06a4308_1
sip=4.19.8=py37hf484d3e_0
six=1.15.0=py_0
sqlite=3.33.0=h62c20be_0
tk=8.6.10=hbc83047_0
tornado=6.0.4=py37h7b6447c_1
wheel=0.35.1=py_0
xz=5.2.5=h7b6447c_0
zlib=1.2.11=h7b6447c_3
zstd=1.4.5=h9ceee32_0
matplotlib=3.0.2=py37h5429711_0
```

Comment: In which environment are you installing the packages? Is it base environment? If not, did you activate newly created environment using conda activate <env_name> before checking the matplotlib version?

Comment: Yes I forget to mention that, after creating I conda activate, then I test packages.
I'm sure to test matplotlib version in the good environment because python version environment is 3.7.9 like in package list file and out of environment my python version is 3.6.5

Comment: I suggest to execute conda update conda and then install only required packages like matplotlib=3.0.2 from a file. I guess conda takes care of all the dependant intermediate base packages required for main package while creating env itself. No need to put those intermediate packages like you have put matplotlib-base=3.3.2 in your file. That might be creating conflict between versions.

Comment: ok so, if I understand, the exported files I've generate is to much full, I've to clean it up before with only necessary packages and without dependencies

Comment: correct! You'll have to cleanup the requirements file and add only necessary packages.

Comment: Same problem with package list only containing:
basemap=1.2.0=py37h856778e_4
matplotlib=3.0.2=py37h5429711_0
netcdf4=1.5.3=py37hbf33ddf_0
numpy=1.19.2=py37h54aff64_0
python=3.7.9=h7579374_0